# Switches wired in parallel in one box

Tags: wiring, dimmer-switch

I wanted to replace a broken dimmer switch. I took off the plate and the switches came out but I don’t know how to put them back together.

Both switches were wired together, in parallel. Two switches controlling two separate lights. [image]

See photo below

Answer (score 2):

The wiring to the switches looks *strange*. The basic setup should be:

Three cables come into the box. Each one has hot or switched hot (black), neutral (white), ground (bare). One is from the panel, one is for switch 1, one is for switch 2.

All the bare wires should go to ground screws in the box, since you have a nice metal box.

All the neutral wires should be connected together (they are) with a wire nut. If you ever need neutral for a smart switch, timer, etc. then the neutral wire is *added* to that group, possibly with a new larger wire nut.

The hot wire from the panel (presumably the wire currently attached to the hanging switches) should go to a wire nut with two short black wires attached to it, one for each switch. Those short wires (pigtails) should go to the "hot" or "line" connection if the switch has "hot" and "switched hot" or "line" and "load" or similar. Simple switches don't care, but smart switches, dimmers, timers, etc. often (not always) do. If you do it this way, there are no wires directly connecting the switches, which makes working on them separately easier.

The other two black wires go to the "switched hot" or "load" connections on the switches.

There is no need for ground wires to the switches because you have a metal box.

Comment: Would like to see more/better pictures also.  Right now it looks like one switch controls the other.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I resolved this:
I pulled out all the wire nuts and switches.
Put power back on and used a tester to find the hot wire from the panel (it was not the wire I thought it was at first glance)
Reconnected all neutrals, connected the new switches together with hot from panel (see yellow wire nut in photo).
Connected the other side of each switch to their respective lamps.
Thank you manassehkatz for the descriptive help!

Comment: This should probably be a comment rather than an answer. Kudos to you on figuring out the problem and following up with your solution.

Comment: This should either be a comment on MannassehKatz's answer or here as a standalone answer.